# Turn on a toggle with a state when view appears SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I save the state from the toggle in a UserDefault. But I dont know how to write that the toggle is turning on or off when the view appears.

```
HStack {
                    Toggle(isOn: $isOnorOff) {
                        
                        Text(isOnorOff ? "ON" : "OFF")
                        
                        
                    }
                    .animation(.easeInOut)
                }
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.isOnorOff.toggle()
                    self.test()
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        .onAppear {
//            Turn the toggle on or off with UserDefaults
        }

func test(){
        
        var onoff = isOnorOff ? "on" : "off"
        let defaults = UserDefaults()
        defaults.set(onoff, forKey: "onOrOff")
        print(defaults.object(forKey: "onOrOff"))
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the value from `UserDefaults`

```
.onAppear {
    isOnorOff = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "onOrOff") == "on"
}
```

Comment: I want to know how I can turn the switch on with code?

Comment: Set `isOnorOff = true`.